# Altium 17 PCB component issue

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, embedded, schematics, altium

I'm new to Altium 17. Before that, i was using Altium 14 and things were pretty good. I have a problem about components on PCB.

In schematic, whenever i use "update PCB Document", components spread out everywhere of screen. Is there any solution to align them in order? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing I experience whenever my zero-registration in the component footprint is off by a lot. It looks like your components have a large difference from the Y-zero-point to the actual pad.

Try opening the footprint editor, press **E** for *Edit*, **F** for *Set Reference*, and choose *Pin 1*, *Center* or *Location*.

Pin 1 sets the origin in the center of your Pin 1 (obviously), Center sets the origin in the center of your component horizontally and vertically and Location lets you select an origin at any point on your grid.

**Edit:**
Oh, and after doing this, delete the components from your layout and do another "Update PCB Document" to reimport the components to good default locations.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your interest. I got question to you. When you say "try opening the footprint editor," you mean footprint manager? (btw, i took these components from vault explorer, not from my library)

Comment: I meant to edit the component via the PCB Library - I have no experience using the Vault functionality, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think this is true, because he's not using the "Update from PCB Libraries," he's talking about updating the PCB when making changes to Sch.  This is the correct behavior of Altium to place a *new* component off the board so that you can tell it's not been placed yet.  If you modify an existing component, it will update it in place.  You can go to the PCB panel, click "Outside Board Components" and select them all, then Tools --> Component Placement --> Arrange within Rectangle

Comment: Yes, @JoelWigton, but his problem is that the new components are placed outside of the maximum zoomed out area, so the components can't be selected. 

Your solution to the weird placement is a good one which I didn't know about (and an answer to the actual question asked - post it as an answer?), but it's still very nice (in fact, I'd call it vital!) to have a proper origin in a component :)

Comment: True that on the origin!

Comment: I tried to apply @JoelWigton 's answer, but i couldn't draw a rectangle. Too weird... (Btw, some components are out of screen.)

Comment: @Griffio, don't forget when you draw the rectangle, don't click and drag a bounding box.  Click once to define the first corner and then again to place the other corner of the rectangle.  Many of Altium's commands, including this one, give you a text hint at the bottom of the layout window (right below the different layers to filter).  There it will show you to do a single click for that command.